# DiscretizeRegion fails for a triangular region

Tags: bugs, computational-geometry, regions, discretization

**Bug introduced in 10.2.0 or earlier and fixed in 11.0.0**

---

I define an implicit region like

```
R = ImplicitRegion[
  0 < Sin[u]/Cos[v] < 1 && 
   0 < Sin[v]/Cos[u] < 1, {{u, 0, 2}, {v, 0, 2}}]
```

But when I try to do

```
DiscretizeRegion[R]
```

Mathematica 10.4 seems to hang and doesn't return any result. This is strange, because the region is really just a simple triangle

```
RegionPlot[0 < Sin[u]/Cos[v] < 1 && 0 < Sin[v]/Cos[u] < 1, {u, 0, 2}, {v, 0, 2}]
```

[image: triangle]

and discretization of a more complex region like

```
DiscretizeRegion[ImplicitRegion[0 < Sinh[u]/Cosh[v] < 1 && 0 < Sinh[v]/Cosh[u] < 1, 
                 {{u, 0, 2}, {v, 0, 2}}]]
```

works without problems. What is the problem with my implicit triangle?

Comment: I can confirm that this problem is also present in MM 10.2 running on Mac OS.

Comment: With version 10.4 on Windows 7 x64 `DiscretizeRegion[R]` returns the result after 6m34s of work on my system ([screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XDMkO.png)).

Comment: Could you report this as a bug to Wolfram Research and add information on the case number they give to it?

Comment: I reported a bug to Wolfram and they opened CASE:3585657. They also said, that DiscretizeRegion can be sped up by specifying the Method to use (e.g. Boolean or RegionPlot), e.g. DiscretizeRegion[R, Method -> "RegionPlot"] .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you've uncovered a bug. I can confirm this behavior in 10.3.1 and 10.4. You can still discretize your region using `DiscretizeGraphics` though:

```
r = DiscretizeGraphics@
     RegionPlot[0 < Sin[u]/Cos[v] < 1 && 0 < Sin[v]/Cos[u] < 1, {u, 0, 2}, {v, 0, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And if you want finer areas, use `DiscretizeRegion`:

```
DiscretizeRegion[r, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]